# how to divide time php

Tags: php, time

I want to divide time to an integer value:

```
1-> 6.15AM till 7.00AM
2-> 7.00AM till 7.45AM
3-> 7.45AM till 8.30AM
4-> 8.30AM till 9.15AM
------BREAK----------- 15 minutes
5-> 9.30AM till 10.15AM
6-> 10.15AM till 11.00AM
7-> 11.00 till 11.45AM
-------BREAK---------- 15 minutes
8-> 12.00 till 12.45PM
9-> 12.45PM till 1.30PM
10-> 1.30PM till 02.15PM
```

Anyone can help me...?
thanks before..!

Comment: Hint: You cannot divide times, only numbers.

Comment: Instead of creating times like 7.00, lose the dot and get 700. Then it's just as easy as 1,2,3 to divide time.

Comment: to add to what @PENDO says - if you do that, you'd need to switch to a 24 hour format so you can differentiate between am and pm.

Comment: This question would probably make more sense with some code.

Answer (score 0):

check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php it might me able to help you, try converting the times into unix timestamps maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try, you might have to change the ranges a bit (i am too lazy to do the exact calculation)

```
$time = time(); // or if your time is in string format use $time = strtotime('10:15 AM');
$seconds_elapsed = $time % 86400; // Seconds since midnight
$mins_elapsed = $seconds_elapsed / 60;
$mins_split = floor($mins_elapsed  / 15); // Split into 15 mins intervals

if ( $mins_split >= 25 && $mins_split <= 36) {
    $index = ($mins_split - 25) / 3;
} elseif ($mins_split >= 38 << $mins_split <= 47) {
    $index = ($mins_split - 38) / 3;
} else {
    $index = ($mins_split - 48) / 3;
}
```