# php calculate time difference in percentage

Tags: php, time

How can I calculate percentage between two time values in php:
Completed time 4min. and 35sec. Maximum time 11min.
What would the remaining 6min and 25sec be in percentage?

Comment: `$time / 100` it's basic math or `$time * 100`. The / is the "divide" arithmetic operator and `*` multiply. Percent is per 100's. Have you attempted anything, or code to show us?

Comment: convert maximum time to seconds, convert actual time to seconds, and divide the numbers. It isn't too hard.

Comment: Downloading is almost 43% complete

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5910755/ --- http://stackoverflow.com/q/365191/ --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make those minutes into seconds:

4 min 35 sec = 275 seconds

11 min = 660 seconds

Your percentage of remaining time will be (275 / 660) * 100. The percentage of time left would be ((660 - 275) / 660) * 100. Of course, that's all in seconds. Don't know how you are receiving that time in php, but it might look like:

```
$maxTime = 660;
$timeTaken = 275;

$percentage = ($timeTaken / $maxTime) * 100;
// To get percentage of time left
$percentLeft = (($maxTime - $timeTaken) / $maxTime) * 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have minutes and second separately, it will be:

```
$min = 4;
$sek = 35;
$maxmin = 11;
$percentage = round((60*$maxmin - (60*$min + $sek))/($maxmin*60)*100,2);
```

result is 58,33

Comment: 58,33 is completely wrong. Not even 5 minutes of 11 minutes is over 50%.

Comment: Question was "What would the remaining 6min and 25sec be in percentage"